# What's the meaning of these 2 lines of this song (焚城雪)?

Tags: translation, meaning

Can anyone help me interpret the meaning of these lines
绊着三生草 白露湿黄叶
青丝易被尘俗染 唯白发不怯

These lines are taken from the song name [焚城雪](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%84%9A%E5%9F%8E%E9%9B%AA#reference-[1]-23020520-wrap)

Comment: https://chinese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic **Please show your attempt at translation in your question and state which area you are having difficulty with.** Without *homework* this question is very quickly going to be closed. If you want to get an answer and keep it open show what you've done to try and translate it first yourself.

Comment: some help:绊 1) stumble
2) trip
3) entangle, 三生草 a kind of medicinal herb, 白露 Bailu or White Dew, 15th of the 24 solar terms 二十四节气 8th-22nd September 湿 moist,wet,青丝(书) black hair (of a woman or girl)易 easily,被 passive marker,尘俗 the world; vulgar world,mortal world∶ 染 dye, infect 唯 only, 白发 white hair, 怯 afraid，timid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A main characteristic of classical style song is that lyrics are composed by images, few story-telling and statement, so it is hard to tell the meanings of the lyrics, just like it is hard to tell the meanings of a painting.

绊 tie

三生草  a fictional plant for love, inspired by 三生石 I think,  三生 means 前生, 今生, 来生

白露 dew, dew links to `sad` in tradition.e.g. 玉阶生白露，夜久侵罗袜。

黄叶 yellow leaves are links to `fades`, `beauty ages` in tradition, just like flower withers.

青丝 means `hair`, 青丝 白发 always links to `time slip away`

e.g. a famous poem `君不见高堂明镜悲白发 朝如青丝暮成雪`,

不怯 do not worry.